# Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "SetParent failed for Login 'XXX'."

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am creating use for SQL Server 2012 using below code in PowerShell.

```
$login = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Login($server, $sqlUser)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "SetParent failed for Login 'XXX'."

I am not getting this error on local database (database on the machine where PowerShell script was executed). If I pass in a remote server name, then I get the error. Any thoughts on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://glutenfreesql.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/setparent-failed-for-login/) you need to set the domain of your `$server`